# If $Gal(G_f)=S_n$ then show that $Aut(\alpha)$ is trivial

Tags: galois-theory

Suppose $f(X) \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ be a polynomial of degree $n$. Let $K$ be splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Suppose $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})=S_n$ with $n>2$. Suppose $\alpha$ is a root of $f$ in $K$ then prove that the only automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is identity.

I've shown that $f$ is irreducible over $Q$ and $\alpha^n$ doesn't belong to $\mathbb{Q}$ for any $n\geq 4$. Now I'm stuck, can anyone please provide some hint ?

Comment: An automorphism must carry roots to roots, no?

Comment: Yes, but how does that help ?

Answer (score 4):

Any automorphism $\varphi$ of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ maps $\alpha$ to a root of $f$; moreover, $\varphi$ is the identity if and only if $\varphi(\alpha)=\alpha$. Thus it is enough to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ contains no root of $f$ other than $\alpha$.

Suppose for a contradiction than $\beta\in\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is another root of $f$. Then any automorphism $\psi$ of $K$ such that $\psi(\alpha)=\alpha $ must be the identity on $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, so $\psi(\beta)=\beta$. But then it cannot be true that $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q}) =S_n$, as it is alway possible to find a permutation in $S_n$ that fixes an element but not another one when $n\geq 3$.

Comment: Another argument showing that no other root of $f$ is in $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ is that $f(x)/(x-\alpha)$ has to be irreducible over $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ for the splitting field to be of degree $n!$ over the rationals.

Comment: Let me ask you the following question: why any automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ maps $\alpha$ to a root of $f$? It is obvious to me if this automorphism fixes rationals. But it may not fix rationals. Could you explain it, please?

Comment: @ZFR Any automorphism of an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ must fix $\mathbb{Q}$; this is because the set of elements fixed by a given automorphism is a subfield, so it must contain the smallest subfield (i.e. the subfield generated by $1$), which is $\mathbb{Q}$. The same is true if you replace $\mathbb{Q}$ by a finite field with $p$ elements with $p$ prime.